# R-shiny: Varying Slider input range

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny-server, shiny

I'm using shiny leaflet to plot maps. I am taking map inputs dynamically through `selectInput` function. All the matrix that I'm taking are of different dimensions. Now I want to restrict number of rows through `sliderInput` function.

For this I want to make sure that range("selected") = range("sliderInput).

For this one can take following data input:
**Data Input**

```
library(data.table)

    mat1 = data.table(long = runif(40, -87, -80), lat = runif(40, 25, 42), name = letters, state= letters) 
    mat2 = data.table(long = runif(9123, -87, -80), lat = runif(40, 25, 42), name = letters, state= letters) 
    mat3 = data.table(long = runif(722, -87, -80), lat = runif(40, 25, 42), name = letters, state= letters) 
    phys_summ = data.table(long = runif(9845, -87, -80), lat = runif(40, 25, 42), name = letters, state= letters) 
    mat4 = data.table(long = runif(99999, -87, -80), lat = runif(40, 25, 42), name = letters, state= letters)
```

Any idea how can I do it?

**First Edit**
My r-code that is taking matrix dynamically. But slider input is not working properly:
***The R-code:***

```
  library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    {r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()
var=c("matrix 1" = "mat1", 
      "matrix 2" = "mat2",
      "matrix 3" = "mat3", 
      "matrix 4 " =  "mat4" )

shinyApp(
  ui =shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("pid", "1. Select the providers ", var, selected= "mat1", selectize = TRUE ),
      br(),
      #sliderInput("bins", "2, Select the number of BINs for Map", min = 5, max = nrow(get(var$input)), value=10)
      # radioButtons("color", "3, Select the color of histogram", choices =c("Green", "Red", "Yellow"), selected= "Green")
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel('Leaflet Map', leafletOutput("leaflet_map")),
                  tabPanel('Circular Map', leafletOutput("circular_map"))
      )))),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$leaflet_map <- renderLeaflet({
      maptab <- get(input$pid)
      m <- leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
        addMarkers(lng=maptab[,'long'][1:input$bins], lat=maptab[,'lat'][1:input$bins],popup=maptab[,'name'])
      m  # Print the map
    })
    ### Top Doctors circular map
    output$circular_map <- renderLeaflet({
      maptab <- get(input$pid)
      m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
      df = data.frame(
        lng=maptab[,'long'][1:input$bins], 
        lat=maptab[,'lat'][1:input$bins],
        size = runif(input$bins, 5, 20),
        category = factor(maptab[,'state']),
        color = sample(colors(), input$bins)
      )
      m = leaflet(df) %>% addTiles()
      m %>% addCircleMarkers(radius = runif(input$bins, 4, 10), color = c('red','blue','green'))
    })
  }) 

)
```

Comment: Can you show your ui.R and server.R code, or at least enough of it to see what you're doing now with this part?

Comment: Also, [this page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) offers a helpful discussion of building reactive controls. It might answer your question.

Comment: @ulfelder: I have added my code in question itself. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `renderUI({})` in the `shinyServer({})` part of server.R to create the controller that depends on objects created in the server process and then use `uiOutput()` in the right spot in ui.R to display that controller. So, with your script, this would get nested in shinyServer at the same level as your other output-generating steps:

```
output$setSlider <- renderUI({

    sliderInput("bins", "2, Select the number of BINs for Map",
        min = 5, max = nrow([selected data frame]), value=10)

})
```

And then this would go in ui.R where that slider-control code is now:

```
uiOutput("setSlider")
```

Comment: I am getting following error :  
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you've got some other bugs in the process, including the fact that this `renderUI({})` block is looking for a variable named "input" in `var` that doesn't exist. If you can get it pointed at a valid target, it should work. Maybe you want to do selection of the data frame outside the mapping bit as a `reactive({})` step of its own?